# Website Freezes on the first load

Tags: performance, joomla

when i first load my website it completely freeze for a few seconds. After first load is all ok. I looked in console and it says there is problem with document.write() and i don't know what it is. I am using JOOMLA! 2.5

http://www.job-point.cz/index.php/zajemci-o-praci

Comment: Works fine for me in Firefox, Chrome and IE11

Comment: Strange when i first time load the page it was ok, but when i switch to "Zajemci o praci" it freeze for a while.

Comment: the only document.write you have on that page are the email obfuscator plugin, and they are correct. No slowdown on my side as well.